# How is the potential in multipole expansion independent from the origin chosen?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, multipole-expansion

Consider a charge distribution $\rho(x',y',z')$ and a point $P=(x,y,z)$ where we want to calculate the potential with multipole expansion.

Suppose also that the total charge is zero, that is $$Q=\mathrm{\int \int \int \rho(x',y',z') dx'dy'dz'=0}$$

Therefore the dipole moment of the distribution $\bf{p}$

$$\bf{p} = \mathrm{\int \int \int \rho(x',y',z') (x',y',z') dx'dy'dz'}$$

**does not** depend on the origin of the frame of reference chosen.

Nevertheless the potential is given by

$$V(x,y,z)=\frac{\bf{p} \cdot \mathrm{ (x,y,z)}}{\mathrm{4\pi \epsilon_0 \,\,\,(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}}$$

And the vector $(x,y,z)$ **does depend** on which origin is chosen.

But the potential $V(x,y,z)$ should be indipendent from the choice of reference, so can this be? What am I missing?

Comment: What is $\rho(x',y',z') (x',y',z')$? Nevertheless, a mean value over the whole space is naturally independent of the origin of the frame, whereas a punctual value of the field does depend on the origine of that frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dipole term in the potential $V(\vec{r})$ is not the exact potential, but is instead the second term in the multipole expansion:
$$
V(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \left[ \frac{Q}{r} + \frac{\vec{p} \cdot \hat{r}}{r^2} + \frac{Q_{ij} \hat{r}_i \hat{r}_j}{r^3} + \dots \right]
$$
where $Q_{ij}$ is the quadrupole tensor;  the dots indicate terms due to the octopole moment, hexadecupole moment, etc.  All of the multipole moments depend on the choice of origin;  and in particular, having zero net charge does not guarantee that the *higher-order* terms stay the same when you shift your origin.  Even if you have a configuration that is a "pure dipole" relative to one origin (with $Q_{ij} = 0$ and similarly for higher moments), this configuration will have a non-zero quadrupole moment as measured relative to some other origin, and these additional multipole moments will "correct" the shifted dipole potential $V(\vec{r}')$ so that it agrees with the original potential $V(\vec{r})$.

To illustrate this, suppose we have two point charges $\pm q$ at $\vec{r} = \pm (d/2) \hat{z}$ respectively.  With respect to this origin, the net charge is zero, the dipole moment is $\vec{p} = q d \hat{z}$, and the quadrupole moment is
$$
Q_{ij} = \sum_\alpha q_\alpha \left(r_{\alpha i} r_{\alpha j} - r_\alpha^2 \delta_{ij} \right),
$$
where the sum runs over the two charges.  This can easily be seen to vanish ($Q_{ij}=0$), since the quantity in brackets is the same for both charges and they have opposite sign.

Now let's look at the same charge configuration relative to a new origin, such that the charge $+q$ is at $d \hat{z}$ and the charge $-q$ is at the new origin.  This is the same configuration, just shifted "up" by a vector $d \hat{z}/2$.  Again, the net charge is zero, and the dipole moment is $\vec{p} = q d \hat{z}$.  But the quadrupole moment is now non-zero;  $\vec{r}_\alpha = 0$ for the negative charge, and the sum now contains a term only due to the positive charge:
$$
Q_{ij} = q (r_i r_j - d^2 \delta_{ij}) = \begin{bmatrix} - d^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -d^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2d^2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Relative to this origin, the multipole expansion of the potential will contain not just a dipole term but also a quadrupole term (and presumably higher-order multipole terms as well.)  Thus, the potential expressed in the new coordinates will have a different form than the potential expressed in the old coordinates;  and both expressions would correspond to the same potential $V(\vec{r})$.

This is a general fact about multipole moments, by the way:  the lowest non-zero multipole moment is always independent of the origin, but higher-order multipole moments will generally change when you change the origin.  The statement with "monopole moments" is obvious:  if we have a configuration with a net charge (i.e. monopole moment), then the charge is independent of the origin, but the dipole moment is generally not independent of the origin.  If in the above sentence you replace "charge" with "dipole moment" and "dipole moment" with "quadrupole moment", it remains true.

Comment: Hi, I saw your [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80811/tensors-with-mixed-symmetry) on Mathematica SE but I don't have an account there. I would like to ask if there is a general method to count the number of independent components of tensors with mixed symmetry? You made a much-needed point that tensors of mixed symmetry do not in general exhibit the same symmetry in their components, except for totally symmetric and antisymmetric ones. Is there a way to count systematically from the Young tableaus?

Comment: @VincentThacker:  yes there is. That would probably make a good question on this site or on [Math.SE], but if you don’t want to do that the key words to search for are “hook length formula”.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but I don't think the hook-length formula is what I'm looking for. Consider a rank-3 tensor in 3 dimensions, which has 27 components. There are 3 partitions (3), (2,1) and (1,1,1) which are also Young diagrams. The diagram (3) has ${5 \choose 3} = 10$ independent components, while the diagram (1,1,1) has ${3 \choose 3} = 1$ components. Now comes the difficult part which is (2,1). The hook-length formula says that there are 2 tableaus, but am asking how we can derive the number of components to be 16 (but generalized to higher ranks). Or am I just confused?

Comment: Hmm, you’re right. I know there’s a way, but I must be misremembering it. I recommend you ask this as a new question; comments aren’t the best place for this sort of discussion.

Comment: I know, I asked this in a comment because you did briefly mention in your answer on how to find that number, which is the part with GroebnerBasis. I would really appreciate it if you could point me to a book or pdf that describes the general counting method. Thanks!

Comment: @VincentThacker:  You want [the hook length formula for semistandard Young tableaux,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Dimension_of_a_representation) rather than for standard Young tableaux. I can't recall where I read about it first;  my go-to reference for this stuff is of Hamermesh's *Group Theory and its Application to Physical Problems*, but it doesn't appear to be in there. There's a citation on the Wikipedia page that might discuss it further. Also, in the case you mention, the decomposition is $27 = 10 + 2\cdot8 + 1$—there are two irreducible 8-D subspaces of mixed symmetry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am also using Hamermesh, and with some more experimentation and research I already figured that out. The total number of independent components, $3^r$  is just the number of standard tableaus times the number of semistandard tableaus, summed over all possible Young diagrams (partitions). However, I have yet to see the intuition behind why these two quantities (independent components and semistandard tableaus) are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Your potential ($V(x,y,z)$) is the product of a function ($\bf{p}$) which **does not** depend on the origin of the reference frame by a function (${\mathrm{ (x,y,z)}}/{\mathrm{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}}$) which **does** depend on the origin of the reference frame, hence it depends on the choice of origin of the reference frame.

Besides, if the potential $V(x,y,z)$ was independent from the choice of origin, it would be constant, which is very unusual for a potential.