# Why does the electric field strength for a dipole go as $1/r^3$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, dipole, multipole-expansion

I've been given the following graphic to help wrap my head around this.

If the potential can be shown to represent a $1/r^2$ relation, then I'm more than happy to accept that the electric field is hence a $1/r^3$ relation, but I need to accept the first part first:

[image]

Since $V = \frac{kQ}{r}$, this basically implies that
$$r = \frac{bc}{c-b}$$
given the geometry of this graphic, yet I simply do not see it.

Comment: Duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/378654/

Comment: Have you studied the multipole expansion of the electric potential yet?  See, for example, [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/303361/9887)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the field of an electric dipole drop off as $1/r^3$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184211)

Answer (score 3):

The important *physical* interpretation that you need to keep in mind is that the charges are opposite, so the $1/r$ pieces of their potentials cancel out.  We'll see this happen explicitly in the math in the correct derivation.

But it also explains why your logic isn't quite enough to *understand* what's going on: You really do need those two opposite charges to cancel out the $1/r$ pieces.  So you shouldn't start from just $V = kQ/r$ and then find the approximation for $r$ by plugging in the correct answer that you don't yet understand.  That's not a helpful way of going about it.  Instead, you should do the full derivation yourself.

First of all, I hope you can see from the geometry that
\begin{equation}
  r \approx b + \frac{LM}{2} \approx c - \frac{LM}{2}.
\end{equation}
The reason is that as you take $P$ very far away, those lines $c$, $b$, and $r$ all become basically parallel, and they squeeze down onto each other.  So $c$, $b$, and $r$ just represent different points along (roughly) the same line.

Now, accepting the equation above, you can immediately see that $LM \approx c-b$.  You can also see that
\begin{align}
  r^2
  &\approx \left(b + \frac{LM}{2}\right)\left(c -\frac{LM}{2} \right) \\
  &\approx bc + (c-b)\frac{LM}{2} - \frac{LM^2}{4} \\
  &\approx bc + LM\frac{LM}{2} - \frac{LM^2}{4} \\
  &\approx bc + \frac{LM^2}{4}
\end{align}
But when $r \gg a$ (and because $a \geq LM$), we know that $LM^2/4$ must have a small effect on the result, so we can just ignore it: $r^2 \approx bc$.  That explains the two approximations shown in your figure.  But I argue that's not enough to actually understand the total potential.

So onto the real derivation.  You'll agree that (without any approximation) the full expression for the potential is
\begin{align}
  V
  &=
  \frac{kQ} {b} - \frac{kQ} {c}.
\end{align}
Note that crucial minus sign!  Next, we can start inserting our approximations:
\begin{align}
  V
  &\approx
  \frac{kQ} {r-LM/2} - \frac{kQ} {r+LM/2} \\
  &\approx
  \frac{kQ} {r-\frac{a\cos\theta}{2}} - \frac{kQ} {r+\frac{a\cos\theta}{2}} \\
  &\approx
  \frac{kQ} {r} \frac{1}{1-\frac{a\cos\theta}{2r}} - \frac{kQ} {r}
 \frac{1}{1+\frac{a\cos\theta}{2r}}
\end{align}
In that last line, I haven't done anything fancy; I've simply pulled out the denominator.  But now, that lets us use the approximation $\frac{1}{1 \pm x} \approx 1 \mp x$ for small $x$.  In this case $x$ is $a\cos\theta / 2r$, and since $r \gg a$ this is small, so we can use that approximation:
\begin{align}
  V
  &\approx
  \frac{kQ} {r} \left(1+\frac{a\cos\theta}{2r}\right) - \frac{kQ} {r} \left(1-\frac{a \cos\theta}{2r}\right) \\
  &\approx
  \frac{kQ} {r} \frac{a\cos\theta}{r} \\
  &\approx
  \frac{kQa\cos\theta} {r^2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The key point is that $r$ (the distance to the center of the dipole) is not the same thing as the distances $b$ and $c$ from your test charge to the positive and negative charges of the dipole.

If the dipole separation isn't very large, then that isn't a big deal, as $1/r$ and $1/b$ will generally be quite similar, but they will have slight differences, and those are easy to calculate as a power series in $a$ when that is small:
$$
\frac{1}{b} = \frac1r + \frac{a\cos(\theta)}{2r^2}+ O\left(\frac{a^2}{r^3}\right) \approx \frac1r + \frac{a\cos(\theta)}{2r^2}.
$$

Now, here is the other important bit: because the charges are equal but opposite, the leading term in this series ($1/r)$ will be the same, so it will cancel out, but the corrections go in opposite directions, so that when you subtract the two potentials, the corrections add constructively:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{b} &\approx \frac1r + \frac{a\cos(\theta)}{2r^2} \\
\frac{1}{c} &\approx \frac1r - \frac{a\cos(\theta)}{2r^2} \\
\implies \frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{c} &\approx \frac{a\cos(\theta)}{r^2}. \\
\end{align}
This is where the $\propto 1/r^2$ potential comes from - as a leading-order correction to the two distances, and it is most cleanly obtained through the Taylor series of $1/b$ when it is displaced.

That means that, if you insist on seeing things on the specific geometry of your diagram, then the geometry is only exact in the limit where $r\gg a$, i.e. when the lines $(-Q)P$, $LM$ and $(+Q)P$ are parallel; if they're *not* parallel, then the identity $c-b=LM$ is false. That means that the geometric identity you've written down,
$$
r= \frac{bc}{c-b},
$$
can never be right, because it makes no reference to $a$. If you want to build a version of that identity which does hold, then your best bet is to work from the cosine law of both triangles,
\begin{align}
b^2 & = r^2 + \frac{1}{4}a^2 - ra\cos(\theta),\\
c^2 & = r^2 + \frac{1}{4}a^2 + ra\cos(\theta).
\end{align}
Thus:

- If what you want is the potential, then the thing to do is to re-phrase these as
  $$
  \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac ar\cos(\theta) + \frac{a^2}{r^2}}},
  $$
  and expand the square root using Newton's binomial series.
- If what you want is the length difference $c-b$, then that's best done via
  $$
  b-c = r\left[\sqrt{1+\frac ar\cos(\theta) + \frac{a^2}{r^2}} - \sqrt{1-\frac ar\cos(\theta) + \frac{a^2}{r^2}}\right] 
  $$
  and again expanding using the binomial series.
- If what you want is a correct version of $r=bc/(c-b)$, then you can put in those expressions to get
  $$
  \frac{bc}{c-b} \approx \frac{r^2}{a\cos(\theta)},
     $$
  and since you're looking at the $r\gg a$ limit, that tells you just how wrong the $r=bc/(c-b)$ identification is in this geometry.